# Android React Native error "Could not find support-annotations.jar"

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal

I have a react-native application, and when trying to run on android or compile the apk I receive this error:

```
react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Running C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-onesignal'.
   > Could not find support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/24.0.0/support-annotations-24.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I've tryed in another machine and it works correctly, but not in my computer. I've checked versions and everythings seems ok. I am runing Windows 10.

This is my configuration:

Application package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@remobile/react-native-toast": "^1.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "native-base": "^0.5.22",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-native": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^1.1.8",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-gifted-listview": "0.0.15",
    "react-native-google-location-fixed": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-lightbox-android": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-side-menu-fixed": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Applications versions:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

> npm -v
4.1.2

> node -v
v6.9.4

> sdkmanager.bat --list
Installed packages:
  Path                              | Version | Description                       | Location
  -------                           | ------- | -------                           | -------
  build-tools;23.0.1                | 23.0.1  | Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1    | build-tools\23.0.1\
  build-tools;23.0.2                | 23.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2    | build-tools\23.0.2\
  build-tools;25.0.2                | 25.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2    | build-tools\25.0.2\
  docs                              | 1       | Documentation for Android SDK     | docs\
  extras;android;m2repository       | 42.0.0  | Android Support Repository, re... | extras\android\m2repository\
  extras;google;g...e_play_services | 38.0.0  | Google Play services, rev 38      | extras\google\g..._play_services\
  extras;google;m2repository        | 42.0.0  | Google Repository, rev 42         | extras\google\m2repository\
  extras;google;usb_driver          | 11.0.0  | Google USB Driver, rev 11         | extras\google\usb_driver\
  extras;intel;Ha...ecution_Manager | 6.0.5   | Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator... | extras\intel\Ha...cution_Manager\
  extras;m2reposi...ver;1.0.0-beta4 | 1       | Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.... | extras\m2reposi...er\1.0.0-beta4\
  extras;m2reposi...out;1.0.0-beta4 | 1       | ConstraintLayout for Android 1... | extras\m2reposi...ut\1.0.0-beta4\
  patcher;v1                        | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v1              | patcher\v1\
  patcher;v3                        | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v3              | patcher\v3\
  patcher;v4                        | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4              | patcher\v4\
  platform-tools                    | 25.0.3  | Android SDK Platform-Tools        | platform-tools\
  platforms;android-16              | 5       | Android SDK Platform 16, rev 5    | platforms\android-16\
  platforms;android-21              | 2       | Android SDK Platform 21           | platforms\android-21\
  platforms;android-22              | 2       | Android SDK Platform 22           | platforms\android-22\
  platforms;android-23              | 3       | Android SDK Platform 23           | platforms\android-23\
  platforms;android-24              | 2       | Android SDK Platform 24, rev 2    | platforms\android-24\
  platforms;android-25              | 3       | Android SDK Platform 25           | platforms\android-25\
  sources;android-21                | 1       | Sources for Android 21            | sources\android-21\
  sources;android-22                | 1       | Sources for Android 22            | sources\android-22\
  sources;android-23                | 1       | Sources for Android 23            | sources\android-23\
  sources;android-24                | 1       | Sources for Android 24            | sources\android-24\
  sources;android-25                | 1       | Sources for Android 25            | sources\android-25\
  system-images;a...-16;default;x86 | 5       | Intel x86 Atom System Image       | system-images\a...16\default\x86\
  system-images;a...gle_apis;x86_64 | 12      | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 ... | system-images\a...le_apis\x86_64\
  system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 19      | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys... | system-images\a...oogle_apis\x86\
  system-images;a...;android-tv;x86 | 9       | Android TV Intel x86 Atom Syst... | system-images\a...android-tv\x86\
  system-images;a...ear;armeabi-v7a | 2       | Android Wear ARM EABI v7a Syst... | system-images\a...ar\armeabi-v7a\
  tools                             | 25.2.5  | Android SDK Tools 25.2.5          | tools\
```

Comment: This probably wouldn't have happened if you refrained from using ReactNative ;-)
Joke aside, if the project is building on another machine, probably you're missing that specific jar file. Maybe you actually have the jar file, but it might be of a newer version, so make a diff between your own Android SDKs and the other machine and see what's the difference. It's likely that the `Android Support Repository` is of a newer/different version on your machine.

Comment: Just a side-note: `         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/24.0.0/support-annotations-24.0.0.jar` doesn't exist in Jcenter apparently - it returns `404`. I don't know how you can change the repository in ReactNative, but you should try that. As to why it works on another machine can be because that machine has the jar file already locally and hence probably won't look for the file online.
Another way to fix it, could be to copy the jar files from one machine to the other and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a version missmatch with gradle. Updating it in build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties seems to work.

```
diff --git a/android/build.gradle b/android/build.gradle
index 46047bd..1ec7ade 100644
--- a/android/build.gradle
+++ b/android/build.gradle
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@ buildscript {
         jcenter()
     }
     dependencies {
-        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
+        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' // Upgrade gradle

         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
         // in the individual module build.gradle files
diff --git a/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties b/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
index 9851e51..625125b 100644
--- a/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
+++ b/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
@@ -2,4 +2,4 @@ distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
-distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
+distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

But I still don't know why in the other machine it worked...

https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/175